# Draftsight Crash

Tags: gtk

I use Draftsight, but with the new version the program crashes at startup. Running from terminal I get the following message:

```
(DraftSight:9303): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 23:17:28.486: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
```

Draftsight is based on Qt. I use ubuntu 18.04. I also installed it on Lubuntu in virtual box, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a conflict between the qt5 libs installed with the system and the ones coming with `draftSight`.

On a 18.04 virtual machine with no qt5 previous installation the SP3 2018 version of `draftSight` installs and runs fine.

On my production machine, still on 16.04 with qt5 installed (compiled even), I had the same issue as OP - `draftSight` crashed from the start, which I solved by removing the platform theme library from `draftSight`s folder:

```
sudo rm /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/PlugIns/QtPlugIns/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so
```